# How to make a bootable usb drive of windows 10 on ubuntu?

Tags: boot, windows-10, flash, iso, drive

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04.2LTS and enjoying it very much. But in case if i need to back to windows then how can i create a bootable pendrive with windows 10 iso file on ubuntu?

Please response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubunt. Please search for an answer to your question Ask Ubuntu before asking a new question. Many things have existing answers

Comment: Almost all older instructions are not valid. Microsoft change the .wim file to be larger than 4GB. But UEFI boot now essentially required must use FAT32 which does not support files over 4GB. The Windows tool to create bootable flash drive splits the .wim file and is best way to create bootable flash drive installer. Create Windows installer with the oversize .wim file
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive &
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy/windows-installer-for-big-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. Yes, It's possible I've decided to get windows 11 for my computer to run alongside Linux .Microsoft just made a free version of windows 11 iso for VM available for download. There are instructions on youtube here /< https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgbzQFN0V54 >/ It's pretty simple.  get the iso file here < https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11 >
Never-mind that other comment with the link to a ten year old article. All that information is obsolete by now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Startup Disk Creator. It is native tool in Ubuntu for making bootable USB. Here I found some download page for windows 10, because official microsoft source does not work for me for some reason: [www.itechtics.com/windows-10-download-iso](https://www.itechtics.com/windows-10-download-iso/).
I think you do not need step by step guide how to use Startup Disk Creator, but if so: [Create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#3-launch-startup-disk-creator).